# Facebook App Center Listing for Website Platform

Tags: facebook

I am trying to list a website with facebook login to App center.

Although I choose the platform as Website in settings I cannot check the platform as website in app details page. I can do that for Website-mobile.

I get this notice "This platform cannot be listed because it is either configured incorrectly or not supported in App Center."

I searched online to solve the issue with no luck. I do not understand why it allows for website mobile platform but not for website.

Comment: I have the same problem, but cannot find the fix.  What did you do to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enter the Site URL under Settings->Website?  If that box is blank, then the option is disabled by Facebook.

NOTE: The idea is that the website will be one that allows users to login with Facebook, so to make sure that people get what they're expecting, be sure to have that feature enabled.

For more details on the App Center Guidelines and configuration settings, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/guidelines

Comment: I have the same problem.  I have my URL entered in Settings>Website for both "Site URL" and "Mobile Site URL".  However, on App Details>App Center Listed Platforms, only "Website - Mobile" enables me to turn on to "YES".  I went through the App Center Guidelines and I cannot find the solution.  I have not uploaded a demo video.  Is this mandatory for "Website" but not "Website - Mobile"?

Answer (score 1):

The Jeremy solution is a required step, but in some cases it may not be enough.

For example if you have selected "Games" as category in the app details --> Category section, try to change it to something else. It worked for me.

Comment: I opened a support ticket with Facebook and they confirmed that you can't add a "Website" platform game as a Game. It's by design, apparently. :-(