# Cannot select Website as platform in Facebook App Details page

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-app-center

I am having the same problem as described at [Facebook App Center Listing for Website Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296779/facebook-app-center-listing-for-website-platform).

However, I already entered my URL into "Site URL" on the "Settings" page and I reviewed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/guidelines and I cannot see what I'm missing or doing wrong.

I have already integrated "Facebook Login" to my website and I would like to add it as a Facebook app.  At https://developers.facebook.com/apps I added my app.  On the "Settings" page, I filled in all of the fields under the "Basic" tab and I entered the same URL to both "Site URL" and "Mobile Site URL" on the "Website" platform.  On the "App Details" page, I filled in all of the fields in the "App Info" section, except "Publisher".  I filled in all of the fields in the "Contact Info" section, except "Marketing URL".  I uploaded the two requested Icons. I uploaded all of the Web and Mobile banners, except "Large Web Editor's Pick".  I uploaded 5 screenshots and the video.

Yet, in the "App Center Listed Platforms" section, the "YES/NO" switch for "Website - Mobile" is on "YES", but the "YES/NO" switch for "Website" is still greyed out with "NO" and when I hover over the ? mark, it shows this:

> This platform cannot be listed because it is configured incorrectly or
>   not supported in our App Center.

Can anyone provide any suggestions on how to get the "YES/NO" switch to work for "Website" platform?

UPDATE:  user2284877 pointed out that Category has to be changed from "Game" to something else.  This worked.  So, is there no way to create a Facebook App for the "Website" platform and that is in the "Game" category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at app details > category
Change it from game(I presume) to fashion or something else :)
worked for me.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  I don't know why "Game" prevented the "Website" platform but not the "Website - Mobile" platform, especially when I have mainly a website, albeit it is responsive for mobile browsers.

Comment: So, is there no way to create a Facebook App on the "Website" platform and that is in the "Game" category?

Comment: I opened a support ticket with Facebook. They confirmed that you can't add a "Website" as a Game, and that it's by design, unfortunately.